# Chemical dictionaries for Android (for instance, body biochemistry)

Tags: android, 3d, educational, dictionary, android-app

I have looked for chemistry dictionaries for Android on the Google Play store and found none.

I was looking for an app where I can:

- key in the name of a molecule found within the body to search. As I type matches are given that start with that name, followed by matches they have that name somewhere in the molecule name, followed by approximate matches. (For example I can type cobalamin or hemoglobin).
- when a match is found, I can click to view the formula name or formulas of the molecules corresponding to that name if there is more than one. When there are more specific, typically, longer names for the molecule types, they are displayed. (For example I might type cholesterol and I can view all three LDH, HDL, and VHDL types of cholesterol).
- I can click on any given molecule in the result to view the diagram notation for that molecule, above, alongside with a 3D, zoomable, molecule, which I can rotate with my fingers on the screen, to view the 3D ball atom representation of the molecule
- I can view information on where in the body the molecule is produced, and where it goes / where it is found
- I can read what the molecule does, where it can cause benefit, where it can cause problems, and associated diseases

That would be nice.

It would be nice if in addition I could find a list of pathways under which such molecules where transformed in a biochemical processes in the body where they may be initial elements, intermediate elements, or final elements, in chains that could be displayed as graphs of reacting or adjoining elements with enzymes along the arcs, and the desired searched molecule as a specially highlighted molecule in the graph.

Thanks.